# People have perceptual characteristics that virtually assure that infants will orient toward them

Tags: pronouns

> By noticing the relation between their own actions and resultant external changes, infants develop self‐efficacy, a sense that they are agents of the perceived changes. Although infants can notice the effect of their behavior on the physical environment, it is in early social interactions that infants most readily perceive the consequence of their actions. People have perceptual characteristics that virtually assure that infants will orient toward **them**. They have visually contrasting and moving faces. They produce sound, provide touch, and have interesting smells. In addition, people engage with infants by exaggerating their facial expressions and inflecting their voices in ways that infants find fascinating. But most importantly, these antics are responsive to infants’ vocalizations, facial expressions, and gestures; people vary the pace and level of their behavior in response to infant actions. Consequentially, early social interactions provide a context where infants can easily notice the effect of their behavior. <Philippe Rochat · 2014 EARLY SOCIAL COGNITION>

What is 'them'? Is it 'perceptual characteristics' or 'People'?

Answer (score 2):

Here, 'them' tags "people", and not "perceptual characteristics".

Although it may perhaps seem ambiguous if the sentence stood on its own, the pronoun "they" in the following sentence refers back to "people", and this makes the meaning of "them" very clear in context.

Compare:

'**Apples have seeds so that they can reproduce.**'  (Are the seeds or the apples reproducing?)

'**Apples have seeds so that they can reproduce. They are also a nice red color, and very nutritious!**' (We are talking about the apples, and not their seeds.)